# DataBinding with Presenter

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building an application using Koin and have been experimenting with something, presenter.
Essentially I wish to use the data-binding lambdas in the xml as an option.
I have the view model with live data and it works fine, but this also works.
Is it wrong to do it this way as well?

This is the way that [android documentation for listener bindings](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#listener_bindings) suggest.

```
/* presenter the kotlin */
class PresenterMe(context: ViewMe){
 fun presented(){
  Toast.makeText(this.context,"PresenterMe,presented()",Toast.Short).show()
 }
}

/* viewme the kotlin */
class ViewMe : AppCompatAtivity(){
 fun bind(){
  val binding: LayoutFileGeneratedFromXML: DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.my_layout)
  mBinding.mPresenter = PresenterMe(this)
  mBinding.executePendingBindings()
 }
}

/* my_layout xml */
<layout>...<data>...<variable>...mPresenter and its package 
somwhere in the file i have a button and i go like this
android:onClick="@{() -> mPresenter.presented()}"
```

Comment: just a note, this sort of resembles a bit of the mvp architecture where the presenter class is complementing the view class.is this correct? please drop feedback. thank you.